# Kotlin variable names: case sensitive?

Tags: kotlin, case-sensitive

Kotlin language spec claims identifiers are case-sensitive yet the following produces compiler error messages because of apparently case-insensitive generated getters/setters.

```
var a=10; var A=20

Clash.kt:1:1: error: platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getA()I):
    fun <get-A>(): Int defined in root package
    fun <get-a>(): Int defined in root package
var a=10
^
```

I understand what is happening but does this seem like the right behavior? Is there a way around this?

Comment: The way around this is to use the naming conventions. Don't name two different things the same way with only capitalization differences. Names in caps should be used only for constants, top-level and `object` member `val`s, and enum values.

Comment: Yea, that's really helpful. I want to use the naming convention Knuth uses for some algorithms. If they are naming "conventions" they should not force a specific use.

Comment: They're not enforced in general, but in this case there's a compilation limitation, as the answer below explains.

Comment: I wish there was some kind of general exception to Kotlin's naming convention, for names and symbols taken from another field where _in that field_ they are case-sensitive. For example, in radiation therapy, doses can range from mBq up to MBq (milliBecquerels to MegaBecquerels) and so a coding convention that hides the distinction between mBq and MBq is literally a life-or-death safety hazard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative workaround is to use `@JvmField` on one or both of the properties. This prevents Java getter and setter methods from being generated, so there are no clashing method signatures to worry about.

Comment: Thanks. Also good :)

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with how the compiler creates getters and setters to match the Java Beans standard. In this case, both of the getters and setters are named `getA()` and `setA(...)` because it tries to use the initial caps version of the field. If these fields were named `aa` and `AA`, however, you'd have `getAa()` and `getAA()` and wouldn't have a name collision.

Comment: Ah. Good. That's actually helpful. Thank you.